# Getting row value in this object

Tags: php

I have the following object:

```
    object(Google_Service_Analytics_McfData)#35 (23) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(4) "rows"
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["columnHeadersType":protected]=>
  string(45) "Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataColumnHeaders"
  ["columnHeadersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["containsSampledData"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["id"]=>
  string(248) "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf?ids=ga:xxxxxxxxx&dimensions=mcf:keyword&metrics=mcf:firstInteractionConversions&filters=mcf:conversionType%3D%3DTransaction;mcf:medium%3D%3Dcpc&start-date=2015-06-01&end-date=2015-08-01&max-results=25"
  ["itemsPerPage"]=>
  int(25)
  ["kind"]=>
  string(17) "analytics#mcfData"
  ["nextLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["previousLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["profileInfoType":protected]=>
  string(43) "Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataProfileInfo"
  ["profileInfoDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["queryType":protected]=>
  string(37) "Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataQuery"
  ["queryDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["rowsType":protected]=>
  string(36) "Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataRows"
  ["rowsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["sampleSize"]=>
  NULL
  ["sampleSpace"]=>
  NULL
  ["selfLink"]=>
  string(248) "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/mcf?ids=ga:xxxxxx&dimensions=mcf:keyword&metrics=mcf:firstInteractionConversions&filters=mcf:conversionType%3D%3DTransaction;mcf:medium%3D%3Dcpc&start-date=2015-06-01&end-date=2015-08-01&max-results=25"
  ["totalResults"]=>
  int(18)
  ["totalsForAllResults"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["mcf:firstInteractionConversions"]=>
    string(2) "31"
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    ["query"]=>
    array(8) {
      ["start-date"]=>
      string(10) "2015-06-01"
      ["end-date"]=>
      string(10) "2015-08-01"
      ["ids"]=>
      string(11) "ga:xxxxxxx"
      ["dimensions"]=>
      string(11) "mcf:keyword"
      ["metrics"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(31) "mcf:firstInteractionConversions"
      }
      ["filters"]=>
      string(47) "mcf:conversionType==Transaction;mcf:medium==cpc"
      ["start-index"]=>
      int(1)
      ["max-results"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["profileInfo"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["profileId"]=>
      string(8) "xxxxxx"
      ["accountId"]=>
      string(8) "xxxxxxx"
      ["webPropertyId"]=>
      string(13) "UA-xxxxxxx-1"
      ["internalWebPropertyId"]=>
      string(8) "xxxxx"
      ["profileName"]=>
      string(24) "xxxxxxx"
      ["tableId"]=>
      string(12) "mcf:xxxxxxx"
    }
    ["columnHeaders"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(11) "mcf:keyword"
        ["columnType"]=>
        string(9) "DIMENSION"
        ["dataType"]=>
        string(6) "STRING"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(31) "mcf:firstInteractionConversions"
        ["columnType"]=>
        string(6) "METRIC"
        ["dataType"]=>
        string(7) "INTEGER"
      }
    }
    ["rows"]=>
    array(18) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(20) "+create online forms"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(10) "+formstack"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(21) "create a contact form"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(21) "create an online form"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "2"
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(12) "form builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "7"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(19) "form builder online"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(13) "form builders"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
      [7]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(12) "form creator"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [8]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(19) "form online builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
      [9]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(24) "free online form builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [10]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(25) "free online forms builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [11]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(19) "online form builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "4"
        }
      }
      [12]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(19) "online form creator"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [13]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(12) "online forms"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [14]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(20) "online forms builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [15]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(23) "online web form builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [16]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(25) "patient registration form"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
      }
      [17]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(17) "web forms builder"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["primitiveValue"]=>
          string(1) "7"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I want to get the value in the "rows" area, e.g. show

+create an online form
0

This is the code I am trying to use to achieve this, however it is not working:

```
foreach ($response->rows as $row) {



                foreach ($row as $cell) {

                    print_r($cell);

                    echo $cell;
                }
            }
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Display any error OR not?

Answer (score 1):

You should get more of an understanding about visibility:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.

Comment: Long story short, you can't retrieve that variable. That's why it's `protected`. The parent of `rows` is `["modelData":protected]`